# Access struct member by an argument of function in C

Tags: c, struct

```
int f(){
    struct NUMBER {     
        int A;
        int B;     
    };

    struct NUMBER *num = malloc(sizeof(struct NUMBER));

    num->A = 1;
    num->B = 2;

    int x = num->B;

    return x;
}


int main(){
    int z = f();
    printf("%d\n", z);   
}
```

Obviously, ./a.out will show `2`.

My question: Can I access struct member by an argument of function? i.e. `f(A)` return `1`, and `f(B)` return `2`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't forget to free the memory you used... `if (num) free(num);` at the end of your function `f` might be useful.

Comment: @ChrisSprague at end of function call?

Comment: @Steephen sure, I think it fits right after the line `int x = num->B;` since we're done using `num` there, right?

Comment: You can not pass a member (identifier) name as a function argument. Instead, use a macro function or pass a relative address with `offsetof`. In addition, the structure definition must be outside the function.

Comment: [Read this](http://xyproblem.info). I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: You can - with macros, some dirty pointer arithmetic, and ugly typecasts. Not recommended, however. Can you tell us in which context you would this function? Maybe there's a cleaner workaround.

Comment: @ChrisSprague - You do not need the if - `free` works when NULL is passed to it

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me

Comment: @EdHeal true, though technically `num` should have been checked immediately after the call to `malloc`... :p

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I just want f() to be reusable.

Comment: Why are you using a struct and why can't you use enums? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks everybody, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all elegant, but I think it shows you what you need to do/know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct NUMBER {
    int A;
    int B;
};

struct NUMBER extNumber = {1, 2};

int f(int offset) {

    int iRet = -1;

    if (offset == offsetof(struct NUMBER, A)) {
        iRet = extNumber.A;
    } else if (offset == offsetof(struct NUMBER, B)) {
        iRet = extNumber.B;
    }

    return iRet;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    struct NUMBER number;

    int iVal;

    iVal = f(offsetof(struct NUMBER, A));
    printf ("A : %d\n", iVal);
    iVal = f(offsetof(struct NUMBER, B));
    printf ("B : %d\n", iVal);

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is helpful to me.

Comment: I'm very glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

> Can I access struct member by an argument of function?

I think you are also assuming struct is not visible outside the function. Now if the person who wrote main does not have visibility into the function (say it is part of a library), then the answer is NO.

Otherwise if author of main can see internals of the function, then: Can someone come up with a fancy way to access struct member inside the function via function argument? Towards that lets think what does f(A) mean? Here, A is a name of struct member, so do you mean passing char A to f and translating that to struct member inside f [e.g. `result = *(int *)num+(inchar-'A')` where `inchar` is aninput parameter to the function of type char]. Similarly, one can imagine other ways.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your problem, the cleanest and most "C-like" solution is to pass a pointer to your struct to f(), where you populate it:

```
typedef struct _NUMBER
    {
    int A;
    int B;
    }
NUMBER;

void f (NUMBER* pvNumber)
    {
    pvNumber->A = 1;
    pvNumber->B = 2;
    return;
    }
```

Call it like this:

```
int main ()
    {
    NUMBER vNumber;
    int    z;

    f (&vNumber);
    z = vNumber.A; // or vNumber.B
    return 0;
    }
```

So you don't select the desired member inside f(), but outside of it.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  you need to define some way to access to member desired, this is usually done with constants, or an enum.  As an aside, you should always check the pointer returned by malloc() before using it.

```
#define  GET_A (0)
#define  GET_B (1)

int f(int selector){

    struct NUMBER {     
        int A;
        int B;     
    };

    int result;
    struct NUMBER *num = malloc(sizeof(struct NUMBER));
    if (!num)
        return -1;  // or some other error code...    

    num -> A = 1;
    num -> B = 2;

    switch(selector)
    {
    case GET_A: result = num->A; break;
    case GET_B: result = num->B; break;
    // etc... if you have more members in your struct.
    default:    result = -1; break;      // some error code.
    }

    free(num)
    return result;
}

int main(){

    int z = f(GET_B);
    printf(  "%d\n" , f(GET_B));
}
```

Comment: But this is a really bad idea, instead `int z = get_b(struct_instance);` and it would be clear an simple. I think the OP wants to do something else that is not related to this question.

Comment: The OP obviously posted a example that is simpler than his actual code. This code structure is useful for introspection.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is helpful to me